# How to fit kitchen cabinets to corners that are not 90 degrees

Tags: kitchens

I'm currently designing a replacement kitchen for my house. The kitchen is U shaped so going across three walls of the house. The middle wall is not 90 degrees to the other two, it is more like 105 degrees to one wall and 75 degrees to the other. How do you usually fit kitchen cabinets to these corners? What are different ways this can be done?

Comment: Is "rebuild the kitchen" an answer you could consider?

Comment: Can you supply more dimensions / measurements? How long are the legs, what are the angles?

Answer (score 2):

Not all corner cabinets make up both sides of a corner. You can get a cabinet for example that is 42" long but with only a 18" door. Another standard cabinet will butt against it to form a corner. Normally a 3" spacer is used to make clearance for drawers and doors to open.  You may need more on your smaller angled corner. I believe they're called blind corner cabinets.  They normally leave an hard to access space but slide outs like in the picture below will help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well if the walls are down I would use this time to get the middle wall at 90 degrees.  You might lose a couple inches of space but your kitchen will look a lot nicer.  It's not just the cabinets but you will have to deal with countertops and other issues too.  We shim out things if you aren't right at 90 but you are a bit off to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could built a custom corner cabinet. alternatively, don't place a corner cabinet, but rather let the cabinets meet at the corner on their outside corners. Then just cover the gap with counter.

Note that the 75 degree wall might cause issues with drawers and doors in the corner. You may want to rethink wrapping cabinets around that particular corner.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution — *if possible* — would be to not use the bottom of the U, but only the legs. You haven't supplied any dimensions, so I have no idea if this is possible, but that would leave you without any corner cabinets to be fitted.

Depending on what you want for your kitchen, you could either leave the bottom completely empty, or use it for something special, such as a free-standing stove or a fridge.